# I am making a prime number checker: when I try to run it, it stopped working

Tags: c, primes, modulus

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x, i, counter = 0;

    printf("Input number!\t");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    for (i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
        if (x % i == 0) {
            counter++;
        }
    }

    if (counter <= 2) {
        printf("%d is a prime number.", x);
    } else {
        printf("%d is not a prime number.", x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It seems the loop part is the problem but I don't know why. I'm very new to programming so please bear with it if its a silly mistake.

Comment: *"when i try to run it, it stopped working"* Please [edit] your question and explain **how** it stopped working.

Comment: The modulo operation `%` does a division. What happens when `i == 0` (first iteration of the loop) and you divide by `i`?

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhh..... I seeee. Thank you very much for your response.@Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Corner case failures: After fixing %0 problem, Code reports all values <= 1 as "prime".  x=INT_MAX also a problem.

Answer (score 2):

> > Try this Code.
>
> Its going to Infinity when divide by ZERO after giving input. Make
>   sure loop start with 1, when division inside loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x,i,counter=0;
    printf("Input number!\t");
    scanf("%d",&x);


    for(i=1;i<=x;i++)
    {
        if(x%i==0)
        {
            counter++;
        }

    }

    if(counter<=2)
    {
        printf("%d is a prime number.",x);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d is not a prime number.",x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Some programmer dude mentioned, you can't do the `x%0` because of division by `0` - this occured on first iteration.

So change your loop to starting from `1` like below:

```
for(i=1;i<=x;i++)
{
    if(x%i==0)
    {
        counter++;
    }

}
```